# Java: How to read and write a XML file with <xliff> tag

Tags: java, android, xml, xliff

Java：How to parse XML file like this,the  really confuses me

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <string name="dialog_presetlist_title">Preset Lists</string>
    <string name="preset_select_name">
          Select "<xliff:g id="preset_name">%1$s</xliff:g>"
    </string>
    <string name="transmit_msg_string">Transmitting at:</string>
</resources>
```

also how to wirte the  tag to a XML file

Answer (score 0):

This xml may look strange but it is a quite legal, well-formed xml. You can parse it with any xml parser like any other xml.

Comment: Yes,it can be parsed with any xml parser.but how to wirte the tag to a XML file